# Why not getting rid of Toxoplasmosis pathogens completely?

Tags: cure, parasites, toxoplasmosis

I read it that a high percentage of mammals, including humans, carry parasites that cause Toxoplasmosis. Through my reading, it appears that it isn't really a "serious" disease. Nevertheless, considering that it is caused by parasite, and it may alter human behavior and cause mental disorders, I want to know:

Is it possible to get rid of it completely? As in purge the body of the parasite.

Why it is being viewed in such a nonchalant manner, in most cases? Why isn't it tackled like some other infections?